# phonegap-googlemaps-plugin not loading kml file

Tags: cordova, kml

I have been trying to load a kml file using phonegap-googlemaps-plugin with no success. I have tested my kml file with googlemaps and google earth and works as expected. I must be doing somenthing wrong, here´s my code:
I am using cordova 5.4.1

```
// JavaScript Document
var map;
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
      var div = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
      // Initialize the map view      
             map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap({
  'backgroundColor': 'white',
  'mapType': plugin.google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
  'controls': {
    'compass': true,
    'myLocationButton': true,
    'indoorPicker': true,
    'zoom': false
  },
  'gestures': {
    'scroll': true,
    'tilt': true,
    'rotate': true,
    'zoom': true
  },
}); 
    map.addEventListener(plugin.google.maps.event.MAP_READY, onMapReady);
    }, false);   
    function onMapReady() {
      var button = document.getElementById("button");
      button.addEventListener("click", onBtnClicked, false);
      map.addKmlOverlay({
  'url': "http://www.promocaototal.pt/bcl.kml"
}, function(kmlOverlay) {});
      }
    function onBtnClicked() {
      map.showDialog();
         }
```

Can someone please tell me what iam doing wrong?
Many thanks!

Comment: Have you whitelisten your kml file?

Comment: Hi Joerg. Yes <access origin="*" /> i also use Inappbrowser and i am able to load external content... Can you see anything wrong with the code?

Comment: Your formatting is a little bit chaotic, but it seams okay. But is your url working, I can't get a file there.

Comment: Sorry  it was a broken link its working now...

Comment: I am refering to the KML file url the kml overlay is still not working in the app... i wonder if its the KML construction but as i said it works with Googlemaps and Earth..

Comment: It was the KML file construction thanks for the help.